# Choosing weights on random forest for imbalanced data with the aim to minimize false positives

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, class-imbalance, grid-search

I am currently dealing with a binary classification task on imbalanced data with the following distribution:

```
y_train: 4981 positive / 863894 negative samples  
y_test:  128  positive / 128309 negative samples
```

The goal is to aim for a high precision (as little false negatives as possible).

How do I go on about choosing the weights for the random forest?

I tried to balance out the `y_train` ratio by assigning weight 1 to "negative" and 173 to "positive", but that still caused all the samples to be assigned to negative.

At this point, should I already consider this a problem with the features used, or should I try to assign higher weights with GridSearch (`roc_auc` as scoring parameter) and set the decision-threshold higher first?

Comment: As an idea: you could use boosting since it often works well on imbalanced data and there are tools to specify the class weights, e.g. in LightGBM (`pos_bagging_fraction`) or in Catboost (`scale_pos_weight`).

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the suggestion! I am planning to try gradient boosting as well, but for my first attempts I will go with random forests as they train faster and have a class_weight option as well

Comment: When you use L1 regularization (aka lasso) you can achieve „automatic“ best feature selection. This would also be an argument for boosting, I guess

Answer (score 1):

I totally missed out on the fact, that the RandomForestClassifier accepts the values “balanced” and “balanced_subsample” to automatically assign the weights as per [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)